# Match comma separated values to single column value in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a list of beer styles called table: `beer_style_list`

Where it contains data like this

[image]

Now I have sample comma separated values like this

`American Lager,American Light Lager,Bock,Bohemian Pilsner,Doppelbock,Märzen,München Helles,Münchner Dunke,Schwarzbier,Vienna Lager`

Im trying to get the IDs of each comma separated values from the `beer_style_list`

output like this

`152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161`

with comma separated too.

Comment: database version?  how many entries in your list at most?  how big can the ids be?

Comment: this is something trivial to do in your client; doing it in sql is possible but is it worth the trouble?

Comment: Load it all in, make a look-up table, and use it in your application layer. One query, infinite low-cost look-ups.

Comment: [FIND_IN_SET()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) might be useful here

Comment: my question here is, what are you going to do with the integer CSV list?

Comment: Im just doing this because I have an excel sheet with multiple records and each one of the rows. has the beer style column that has multiple comma separated values. So I came up with the solution by doing this kind of action.

Answer (score 0):

`GROUP_CONCAT` is designed for this.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) FROM `beer_style_list`
```

Comment: that not the hole issue here, that is simly the small part